# Could not cast value of type(NSSingleEntryDictionary)

Tags: ios, swift3

I am getting the below error. My app is crashing for this reason.

> Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x1015f8210) to 'NSMutableDictionary'

All I am doing is :

```
var tempDict = self.arrayData.object(at: indexPath.row) as!
NSMutableDictionary
```

I have checked the others answers on stack but unfortunately they were not helpful for me.

Can anybody suggest me why this is happening?

**Any help would be higgle appreciated!!**

Comment: downvoter please mention reason!!

Comment: Please mention the reason for down voting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do not use mutable Foundation collection types (`NSMutable..`) at all in Swift. They are not related to the Swift counterparts and you cannot cast an collection object to `NSMutable...`

Declare `arrayData` as native Swift array of dictionaries

```
var arrayData = [[String:Any]]()
```

and change the line to get the dictionary to

```
var tempDict = self.arrayData[indexPath.row]
```

Less code, no type cast and `tempDict` is mutable with the `var` keyword.

Comment: It shows error in another lines.

Comment: You need to replace `add(...` with `append(...` and `object(at index:` and `object(for key:` with index / key subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary denotes  with {} and  Array denotes with [] // In printed response you may have array with ()

So, your tempDict part is Array of Dictionary...You have to parse it like

```
var tempDict = self.arrayData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! [[String : Any]]
```

> although please not use force unwrap .. either use `if let` or `guard` statement

```
if let tempDict = self.arrayData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! [[String : Any]]

{ 
   // do something
 }
else
{

   // catch the error
 }
```

Comment: var tempDict = self.arrayData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! [[String : Any]]
            let tempKey : Int = indexPath.row + 1
            let myString = String(tempKey)
            let tempArr = (tempDict.value(forKey: myString) as? NSMutableArray)?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
            tempArr.replaceObject(at: 1, with: numberOfTaps)
            dict.setValue(tempArr, forKey: myString)

Comment: This is my code. If I update it it shows error in another line.

Comment: what the error.